# how to instrument / measure delays within a loop of multiple Goroutines

Tags: go, rabbitmq, instrumentation

For reproducing an error `(404) Reason: "NOT_FOUND - no queue` when subscribing to  [rabbitmq](https://www.rabbitmq.com/) queues,  I am using the following code to concurrently declare and consume queues:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"
    "sync"
    "time"

    uuid "github.com/satori/go.uuid"
    "github.com/streadway/amqp"
)

func exit1(err error, msg string) {
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("%s: %s", msg, err)
    }
}

func main() {
    rUSER := "bunny"
    rPASS := "test"
    rHOST := "my-rabbit"
    rPORT := "5672"
    rVHOST := "hole"

    // read from ENV
    if e := os.Getenv("RABBITMQ_USER"); e != "" {
        rUSER = e
    }
    if e := os.Getenv("RABBITMQ_PASS"); e != "" {
        rPASS = e
    }
    if e := os.Getenv("RABBITMQ_HOST"); e != "" {
        rHOST = e
    }
    if e := os.Getenv("RABBITMQ_PORT"); e != "" {
        rPORT = e
    }
    if e := os.Getenv("RABBITMQ_VHOST"); e != "" {
        rVHOST = e
    }

    conn, err := amqp.Dial(fmt.Sprintf("amqp://%s:%s@%s:%s/%s",
        rUSER, rPASS, rHOST, rPORT, rVHOST))
    exit1(err, "Failed to connect to RabbitMQ")
    defer conn.Close()

    ch, err := conn.Channel()
    exit1(err, "Failed to open a channel")
    defer ch.Close()

    // buggy part
    args := map[string]interface{}{
        "x-message-ttl": int32(3000),
        "x-expires":     int32(8000), // <-- culprit
    }

    concurrent := 500

    wg := sync.WaitGroup{}
    semaphore := make(chan struct{}, concurrent)

    for i := 0; i < 1000; i++ {
        semaphore <- struct{}{}
        wg.Add(1)
        go func() {
            queueName := fmt.Sprintf("carrot-%s-%s", time.Now().Format("2006-01-02"), uuid.Must(uuid.NewV4()))
            fmt.Printf("Creating queue: %s\n", queueName)
            defer func() {
                <-semaphore
                wg.Done()
            }()
            q, err := ch.QueueDeclare(
                queueName,
                false, // durable
                false, // delete when usused
                false, // exclusive
                false, // no-wait
                args,  // arguments
            )
            exit1(err, "Failed to declare a queue")

            // how to measure here time elapsed between ch.Consume is called

            _, err = ch.Consume(
                q.Name, // queue
                "",     // consumer
                true,   // auto-ack
                false,  // exclusive
                false,  // no-local
                false,  // no-wait
                nil,    // args
            )
            exit1(err, "Failed to register a consumer")
        }()
    }
    wg.Wait()
}
```

Giving more context, the code will work fine and subscribe to all
the `1000` queues when having few concurrent clients `< 100`, but when adding more concurrent clients a kind of "race condition" occurs and clients start to receive an error `404`, this happens because of declaring a TTL for a queue, in this case, 8 seconds:

```
 "x-expires":     int32(8000),
```

A better solution would be to use exclusive queues otherwise, the queue is being deleted before the client can consume it, but within this "buggy" code, I would like to measure the delay is taking between the `ch.QueueDeclare` and the `ch.Consume`.

A client basically is doing:

```
  q, err := ch.QueueDeclare(
            queueName,
            false, // durable
            false, // delete when usused
            false, // exclusive
            false, // no-wait
            args,  // arguments
        )
```

And then:

```
 _, err = ch.Consume(
          q.Name, // queue
          "",     // consumer
          true,   // auto-ack
          false,  // exclusive
          false,  // no-local
          false,  // no-wait
          nil,    // args
        )
```

When having multiple concurrent clients, after doing the `QueueDeclare` there seems to be a delay that reaches up to `8s` seconds before the `Consume` is called and because of this the error `404` but what and how could I instrument, adapt to code to measure this delays?

Comment: Measuring elapsed time is pretty straightforward... `start := time.Now()` at the start of the span you want to measure, then `elapsed := time.Since(start)` at the end of the span. Is that all you're asking?

Comment: true, that definitely could help